# How can i send time after time 12am vb6

Tags: vb6

I have coded it, but it doesn't do what i have coded. Here  is my code looks like:

```
Private Sub timer_Timer()
    dateoutput.Caption = Format(Now, "General date")
        If theTime >= #12:00:00 AM# And theTime <= #11:59:59 AM# Then
            welcome.Caption = "Good Morning"
        ElseIf theTime >= #11:59:59 AM# And theTime <= #6:00:00 PM# Then
            welcome.Caption = "Good Evening"
        ElseIf theTime >= #6:00:00 PM# And theTime <= #11:59:59 PM# Then
            welcome.Caption = "Good Night"
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the expected result and what is the actual?  What does not work?

Comment: The code does not show how `theTime` is being set. If it isn't being set, that's a problem.

Comment: @eglease it doesnt change the welcome.Caption, it just showed the Good Morning one. (FYI i have tried it at night also afternoon)

Comment: @NevylloKalangi Where is 'theTime' set? Without knowing what the value of that is there is no way to know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are comparing something that has a date component to something that doesn't, so you'll never get it to work the way you want.

This is better:

```
Private Sub Timer_Timer()
    Dim theTime As String
    theTime = TimeValue(Now)

    dateOutput.Caption = Format(Now, "General date")

    If theTime >= #12:00:00 AM# And theTime < #12:00:00 PM# Then
        welcome.Caption = "Good Morning"
    ElseIf theTime >= #12:00:00 PM# And theTime < #6:00:00 PM# Then
        welcome.Caption = "Good Evening"
    ElseIf theTime >= #6:00:00 PM# And theTime <= #11:59:59 PM# Then
        welcome.Caption = "Good Night"
    End If
End Sub
```

Also note I've changed the values used for the check ranges slightly.
*Edit* It doesn't like checking "< #12:00:00 AM#" so it needs to be "< #11:59:59 PM#"

Answer (score 1):

you have a little error in 12:00:00 AM  => PM

```
Private Sub timer_Timer()
    dateoutput.Caption = Format(Now, "General date")
        If theTime >= #12:00:00 PM# And theTime <= #11:59:59 AM# Then
            welcome.Caption = "Good Morning"
        ElseIf theTime >= #11:59:59 AM# And theTime <= #6:00:00 PM# Then
            welcome.Caption = "Good Evening"
        ElseIf theTime >= #6:00:00 PM# And theTime <= #11:59:59 PM# Then
            welcome.Caption = "Good Night"
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 12pm is midday, 12am is midnight. So OPs ranges are correct.